# I have received an ActiveRecord Relation, however I need to access the object within the array.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, object, activerecord

I am working on a rails web app and have received an ActiveRecord relation, however I need to access all of the objects in the array. Is there a simple way of achieving this as I can not find anything to help online.

This is the ActiveRecord return with the object within it, but I need the array with all objects in it. Cheers

`[#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Chapter id: 995, description: "hello world", created_at: "2016-08-03 09:43:50", updated_at: "2016-08-03 09:43:50", adventure_id: 787, parent_choice_id: 672>]>]`

Answer (score 0):

`.to_a` is the solution. (http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_a)

But you really should keep the relation as you can use methods like `find`, `where` and other stuff on it.

But ActiveRecord::Relation responds to almost everything that an array does. like `each` as following:

```
# assume that @objects is an ActiveRecord::Relation
@objects.each do |obj|
  puts obj.id
end
```

EDIT:
I just saw that your relation is inside an array. Are you aware of that?